# PyQt4 to PyQt5 -> mainFrame() deprecated, need fix to load web pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I'm doing Sentdex's PyQt4 YouTube tutorial [right here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU). I'm trying to follow along but use PyQt5 instead. It's a simple web scraping app. I followed along with Sentdex's tutorial and I got here:

[image]

Now I'm trying to write the same application with PyQt5 and this is what I have:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self):
        self.app.quit()


url = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/'
client_response = Client(url)

#I think the issue is here at LINE 26
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
print(js_test.text)
```

When I run this, I get the message:

> ```
> source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
> AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'mainFrame'
> ```

I've tried a few different solutions but none work. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Logging QUrl(url) on line 15 returns this value:

> `PyQt5.QtCore.QUrl('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')`

When I try `source = client_response.load(QUrl(url))` for line 26, I end up with the message:

> `File "test3.py", line 28, in <module>
>           soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
>         File "/Users/MYNAME/.venv/qtproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
>           elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
>       TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

When I try `source = client_response.url()` I get:

> ```
> soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
>       File "/Users/MYNAME/.venv/qtproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
>         elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
>     TypeError: object of type 'QUrl' has no len()
> ```

Comment: It looks like mainFrame() is a self defined method within `class Client(QWebEnginePage)`, because it doesn't exist in the class according to the [Qt5 Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html). Are you sure there isn't more to the tutorial that you are missing?

Comment: mainFrame() was a method in PyQt4 with QWebPage:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

Comment: Without knowing much about the webkit it seems that mainFrame() has been absorbed to other functions, where instead you specify whether the frame is the main one or a child frame by using a bool indicator. For example `acceptNavigationRequest(const QUrl &url, NavigationType type, bool isMainFrame)`.

Comment: I could have guessed what you are saying, but as someone who isn't an expert especially in the realm of Python, knowing WHY something doesn't work doesn't help much if I don't know HOW to fix it ---- with code samples.

Comment: @LesPaul. `QtWebEngine` is not a drop-in replacement for `QWebKit` - there are many features that have changed, or are completely missing.

Answer (score 21):

you must call the `QWebEnginePage::toHtml()` inside the definition of the class. `QWebEnginePage::toHtml()` takes a pointer function or a lambda as a parameter, and this pointer function must in turn take a parameter of 'str' type (this is the parameter that contains the page's html). Here is sample code below.

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()


def main():
    page = Page('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
    js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
    print js_test.text

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: This works fine if I need to get just one page. But If I create a loop where a page is downloaded each cycle of the loop python crashes. Any idea what to do ? There isn't any exception or error message - Python itself crashes and OSX offers to submit an error report

Comment: @KaizerSozay i have same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: No idea. Can’t remember what I did

Comment: How does html_str contains html data?

Comment: I tried running this on an event page at Carnegie Hall and I got the pre-rendered version with the script and not the script's results.

https://www.carnegiehall.org/calendar/2022/09/29/Carnegie-Halls-Opening-Night-Gala-The-Philadelphia-Orchestra-0700PM

<html><head>
<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/>
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
</script></head></html>

Answer (score 2):

Never too late...
I got the same issue and found description of it here: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#crashes-on-exit

I followed the advice of puting the QApplication in a global variable (I know it is dirty... and I will be punished for that) and it works "fine". I can loop without any crash.

Hope this will help.