# How can I get output from method of class into global variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, pyqt, global, local

I'm trying to get some datas from a javascript webpage. My code is generating multiple links and parsing them one by one. Parsing outputs are lists. I have written this code with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47381962/984421). But it produces the lists inside a class. I want to insert list items into an sqlite table, and because of this I want to make the local list items global. I've tried to create a global list, put it into the class, and then append to it and return it. I've tried to directly insert them into the database from the `processCurrentPage` method and tried to create a list under the class and reach it by Webpage.list. But none of these methods worked. One of my attempts is here, but not the best one - it's only an example. I've tried many alternatives like this. Can you suggest a good way to handle it please?

P.S: I am new at Python, but researching it for whole two days, and read all class documentation, but couldn't find a way.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4 as bs

class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    alldatas=[]
    def __init__(self):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.handleLoadFinished)

    def start(self, urls):
        self._urls = iter(urls)
        self.fetchNext

    @property
    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            url = next(self._urls)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        return True
    def processCurrentPage(self, html):
        url = self.url().toString()
        # do stuff with html...
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        data = soup.find('div', class_='tablo_dual_board')
        data1 = data.text
        data2 = data1.splitlines()
        self.alldatas+=data2

        if not self.fetchNext:
            QtWidgets.qApp.quit()


    def handleLoadFinished(self):
        self.toHtml(self.processCurrentPage)

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, QWebEnginePage_JavaScriptConsoleMessageLevel, p_str, p_int, p_str_1):
        # disable javascript error output
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # generate some test urls

    onexurl = "https://1xbahis1.com/en/live/Football/"
    r = requests.get(onexurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    income = soup.find_all("ul", {"id":"games_content"})
    links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "c-events__name"})

    urls = []
    for matchlink in links:
        urls.append("https://1xbahis1.com/en/"+(matchlink.get("href")))


    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webpage = WebPage()
    webpage.start(urls)
    print(webpage.alldatas)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a version of your script that should do what you want. The `scrape_page` function is called for each url that is processed, and the data is added to a global `records` list. The `process_records` function is called  **once** after all the pages have been scraped. You can use this function to add the records to your database.

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

records = []

def scrape_page(url, html):
    print('scrape page:', url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.find('div', class_='tablo_dual_board')
    if data is not None:
        records.append(data.text.splitlines())
    else:
        print('error: could not find tablo_dual_board')

def process_records():
    # add record to database ...
    print('process records:', len(records))

def generate_urls():
    onexurl = "https://1xbahis1.com/en/live/Football/"
    reply = requests.get(onexurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reply.content, "html.parser")
    income = soup.find_all("ul", {"id":"games_content"})
    links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "c-events__name"})
    urls = []
    for matchlink in links:
        urls.append("https://1xbahis1.com/en/"+(matchlink.get("href")))
    return urls

class WebPage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WebPage, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.handleLoadFinished)

    def start(self, urls):
        self._urls = iter(urls)
        self.fetchNext()

    def fetchNext(self):
        try:
            url = next(self._urls)
        except StopIteration:
            return False
        else:
            self.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        return True

    def processCurrentPage(self, html):
        scrape_page(self.url().toString(), html)
        if not self.fetchNext():
            process_records()
            QtWidgets.qApp.quit()

    def handleLoadFinished(self):
        self.toHtml(self.processCurrentPage)

    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, QWebEnginePage_JavaScriptConsoleMessageLevel, p_str, p_int, p_str_1):
        # disable javascript error output
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    webpage = WebPage()
    webpage.start(generate_urls())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro thanks again for your help, but after about one minute i run the code Python crashes. Why could it be? It prints "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)" message.

Comment: @AhmetUluer. I'm have just run the script, and it works fine for me. It scraped all the urls and then printed `process records: 16`. How are you running the script? What platform are you on?

Comment: @AhmetUluer. Can you please make sure you run the script in a console using `python script.py` (or if you're on windows, in a command window, using `python.exe script.py`). This should produce a traceback when the error happens.

Comment: It is really interesting, after your comment i've tried again and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Could previous crash's reason be about my PC properties?

Comment: @ ekhumoro As i read "records.append(data.text.splitlines()) Nonetype object has no attribute 'text' " error message from CMD I've tried try, except condition for `records.append(data.text.splitlines())` and it solved the problem. Some of URLs turns with nothing if match has ended, and causes that problem i think.

Comment: Sorry i've not seen your comment, i've done them now. I'm also new on stackoverflow, so i don't know how here works that is the reason :) If it's possible i want to give you millions of upvotes really :)