# How to Scrape Shopify Website Using Beautiful Soup and Get All the Tags(#)

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, shopify, webscarab

I am trying to find all the # elements in a particular webpage by using Beautiful Soup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


source = "https://www.runinrabbit.com/"


def getPageContents(source):

    req = requests.get(source)
    print("req : ",req,type(req))
    print("***************************")
    content = Soup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    print("content data",type(content),content)
    return content
```

Like the content, I am just getting everything else but the tagged value.

e.g., Strings with tags, like below is not getting printed in my function:  getPageContents.

**#marathoner, #winner, #runinrabbit, #topoathletic, #hartfordmarathon, #rabbitpro, #marathon, #olympictrials, #runnergirl, #winning, #finisher, #run, #running, #runner, #runnersofinstagram, #runnersworld, #runnerscommunity, #breezyback, #lightweight, #simple, #runinrabbit, #borntorunfree, #breezyback, #lightweight, #simple, #runinrabbit, #borntorunfree", #racerollcall, #racetime, #runfast, #goodluck, #RADrabbit, #rabbitELITE, #rabbitELITEtrail, #rabbitPRO, #runinrabbit, #borntorunfree"**

Comment: but i dont see these tags anywhere in the website

Comment: Thanks @RahulAgarwal  for extending help. Please try to suggest some solution for this.  The issue is When we do, inspect over the webpage, we can see many #ed values in 'Elements' tab.( I am using google crome browser). But the same is NOT visible in view-source:runinrabbit.com It seems like issue of stackoverflow.com/questions/21069294/… But as now it seems urllib2 is deprecated, not able to resolve by following the same.    Please let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal , I tried following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147601/pyqt4-to-pyqt5-mainframe-deprecated-need-fix-to-load-web-pages   but in PyQt5 its became equivalent to html parser, as this also not getting tagged values.