# Cannot scrape protected email from website

Tags: python, selenium, email, beautifulsoup, data-protection

I want to scrape emails from [this website](https://www.accesswire.com/546227/InterRent-Announces-Voting-Results-from-the-2019-Annual-and-Special-Meeting) but they are protected. They are visible on the website but while scraping a protected email appears which are decoded.

I have tried scraping but got this result

```
<a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#d5a7bba695b9a6b0b2fbb6bab8"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="c0b2aeb380acb3a5a7eea3afad">[email protected]</span></a>
```

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re


r = requests.get('https://www.accesswire.com/api/newsroom.ashx')
p = re.compile(r" \$\('#newslist'\)\.after\('(.*)\);")
html = p.findall(r.text)[0]
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
headlines = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('a.headlinelink')]

for head in headlines:
        response2 = requests.get(head, headers=header)
        soup2 = bs(response2.content, 'html.parser')

        print([a for a in soup2.select("a")])
```

I want the emails that are in the body *e.g. Email: theramedhealthcorp@gmail.com* this email from this site https://www.accesswire.com/546295/Theramed-Provides-Update-on-New-Sales-Channel-for-Nevada-Facility
but the email is being protected, how to scrape it in textual form like real email address?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code first and I too got [email protected]

Then I realized website might be loading that data through JavaScript.

You can get your work done using selenium or any light browser.

I have used PyQt5 library to open the page as it would be opened in a JavaScript enabled browser then I get the source code from it and perform normal BeautifulSoup code.

Prerequisite installations commands (If you are windows user):

To install PyQt5 : `pip install pyqt5`

PyQt5 windows distribution doesn't have PyQtWebEngine we need to install it separately:

```
pip install PyQtWebEngine
```

To render JavaScript based pages using pyqt4 I followed SentDex's video here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU

But it was for pyqt4. To transit from pyqt4 to pyqt5 this StackOverflow answer helped me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432380/8810517

My code:

```py
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage

class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)

        self.html=""
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)

        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_page_load(self):
        self.html=self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print("In on_page_load \n \t HTML: ",self.html)

    def Callable(self,html_str):
        print("In Callable \n \t HTML_STR: ",len(html_str))
        self.html=html_str
        print("In Callable \n \t HTML_STR: ",len(self.html))
        self.app.quit()

url="https://www.accesswire.com/546227/InterRent-Announces-Voting-Results-from-the-2019-Annual-and-Special-Meeting"

client_response= Client(url)

soup = bs(client_response.html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')
#print(len(table))
table = table[len(table)-1]
#print(table)
a = table.find_all('a')
#print(len(a))
for i in a:
    print(i.text)
```

Output:

```py
mmcgahan@interrentreit.com
bcutsey@interrentreit.com
cmillar@interrentreit.com
```